# Simple PHP login: ID wont pass to page but everything else will

Tags: php, html

I am able to pass the user name but i cant pass the id for some reason. going from page 1 to page 2.  In page 2 i echo $result in the html body.  The name on the login screen will be passed over but the id is blank when i show it.  comes up id:name:myName

page1

```
   <?php 

  session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))      {
  $dbu = "myName";
  $dbp = "abc123";
 $uid = "1111";

 $name = $_POST['user'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($name == $dbu && $pass == $dbp)
  {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    header("Location: test.php");
  }
  else
  {    header("Location: unsuccessful.php");    }
}  
 ?>
```

page2

```
 <?php 
 session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
 {
 $uid = $SESSION['id'];
 $name = $_SESSION['user'];
 $result = " id:".$uid."user:".$name;   
  }
 else
{    $result = "not logged in";   }

?>
```

Comment: typo `$SESSION['id'];` lacks the underscore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to this:

```
from ::
$uid = $SESSION['id'];
To
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just complicating issues. Are you  initializing login variables within php codes or are you sending it from a form inputs. 
Any way create table as follows and try to login with the code below. you will be okay.
 This code has been tested and it will work for you

```
create table users(id int  primary key auto_increment, username varchar(100), password varchar(100));
insert into users(username,password) values('sectona','sectona09');




<?php







$db = new PDO (

    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sectona_db;charset=utf8', 

    'root', // username



    'root89' // password

);
?>


<?php
  session_start();

require("pdo.php");


$uname=$_POST["uname"];
$pass=$_POST["pass"];



$statement = $db->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
        AND password = :password 

    ');


    $statement->execute(array(
':username' => $uname,
':password' => $pass));




    if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
// Ensure that session fixation attack is not possible
session_regenerate_id();

           $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $row['username'];


$_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD'] = $row['password'];


echo '<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "welcome.php";
}, 2000);
</script>';



}else{

echo '<font color=red size=2><b>Wrong Login Account</b></font>';

}





?>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
session_start();

Welcome <?php echo  $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']; ?>

?>
```